# C# Data of New Column won't show in Datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

[image]

> So I created a new column named "seatNumber" but it won't show in the Datagridview.

> But the rest of the data are showing and is updating except for the new column.

> I have here a link of the video just in case it can help. https://youtu.be/adsT7h2uh48

> Here is the code of Book Reservation Button:

```
private void reservationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Reservation Button.
        string nameString = nameTextbox.Text;
        string mobileString = mobileTextbox.Text;
        string timeString = timeComboBox.Text;
        string seatNumberString = textBox1.Text;
        bool allPopulatedBool = nameString != string.Empty && mobileString != string.Empty && timeString != string.Empty && seatNumberString != string.Empty;
        if (allPopulatedBool)
        {
            //if the Form are completed.
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=LocalDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
            con.Open();
            string queryString = "INSERT INTO CustomersInfo VALUES(@CustomersName, @CustomersMobile, @CustomersTime, @seatNumber)";

            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
            param1.ParameterName = "@CustomersName";
            param1.Value = nameString;

            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
            param2.ParameterName = "@CustomersMobile";
            param2.Value = mobileString;

            SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter();
            param3.ParameterName = "@CustomersTime";
            param3.Value = timeString;

            SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter();
            param4.ParameterName = "@seatNumber";
            param4.Value = seatNumberString;

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
            command.Parameters.Add(param1);
            command.Parameters.Add(param2);
            command.Parameters.Add(param3);
            command.Parameters.Add(param4);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Reservation has been Successfully Booked!", "Schedule Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            nameTextbox.Text = string.Empty;
            mobileTextbox.Text = string.Empty;
            timeComboBox.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        if (!allPopulatedBool)
        {
            //if the Form are not completed.
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all fields.", "Incomplete Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

[image: I view the data]

Comment: You should post the code in the second forms “Book Reservation” button click event. It is not possible to tell why the seat number value is not displaying without more info. As Gerry B notes, we have to assume that the seat number value is saved to the DB. Since you state… _”I created a new column named ’seatNumber”_ … and we can see the column in the grid and the DB, then, it is not difficult to assume that the portion of the code in the second form’s `Book Reservation` button click event may not have been updated to include the newly added seat number data.

Comment: Also, you commented… _”when I pressed the number it goes to the textbox as a string then assign it as a data same with the other datas”_ … ? … if the seat number column was newly added, then it is safe to assume there was no “seat number” text box before this. Even if it was there, there would not have been any code to get the value from the “seat number” text box and save it to the DB. So, I do not see how this can be the _“same with other datas”_ since it wasn’t there, you must have added the code, or, I am betting you did not update the code to save the seat number to the DB.

Comment: Thank u I'm still searching in the internet on how to update it because I'm not sure how but sure I will edit it and post the code :)

Comment: Ok, you can see the data in the data base. You need to look closer at... when you click on the grids Data source, there are four (4) different sources… are you sure you are picking the right one? Also, in the posted picture, it looks strange that all the column names match the table column names except the seat number. Did you change that columns header text? In the grid its “Seat Number”, in the DB its “seatNumber”? Lastly, if all looks good and the values still do not display, then create a new project and just load the data into a grid without any extra code.

Comment: Ohh thank you I checked it and change it to "seatNumber" it's okay now but it's like this: https://youtu.be/8bg9yi8wyGs

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment but have to post this as an answer; Did you update the binding/data source as well? Seems the column does appear in the DataGridView, your problem is that no data is displaying, which usually points to the binding/data source (SQL) not having that column in it's output and binding correctly.

Comment: Okay I will search it thank you :) I'll tell u later

Answer (score 0):

Also did you actually assign data to the seatNumber field when you accepted the booking?  I saw you select the seat 4 but that doesn't mean it's in the data.

Comment: yup when I pressed the number it goes to the textbox as a  string then assign it as a data same with the other datas